# npm install from the parent directory

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, npm-install, package.json

I have a directory structure like this: `/a/b/c`

Directory `c` contains `package.json` and should contain `node_modules`.
How can I execute `npm install` from inside directory `a`?

I tried this way: `npm --prefix b/c install b/c` but this way, all the symlinks are created directly inside `c` instead of the default `node_modules/.bin`.

Is there any way to achieve that?

node: 6.2.2
npm: 3.10.2

Comment: I don't think so. the current working directory concepts doesn't allow. probably node.js require function stops this.

Comment: I was also thinking about if there are any workarounds if it not possible to pass the path of package.json. Maybe an additional package.json file in /a with custom "npm run" to start a process, change directory to /a/b/c and run "npm install"?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using an npm pre install hook in a `package.json` within your `a` directory is likely the best choice in this situation.

```
scripts: {
    preinstall: `cd b/c && npm install`
}
```

This way running `npm install` in directory `a` will also do the `c` directory install and provide a seamless dev experience.

Answer (score 2):

A bit overkill but may be useful...

With the help of recursion you can find `node_modules`.

you could run this file in a parent directory to find `node_modules` in child directory and pass npm arguments.

**Note**: tested on Windows

```js
var child_process = require('child_process');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var safe = 0;

let args = process.argv.splice(2).toString().replace(/,/g ,' ');
function recurse(_path){
safe ++;
if(safe > 5000){
  console.log('directory may be too large')
  return
}

  if(/node_modules$/.test(_path)){
    let cwd = path.resolve(__dirname ,_path)
    console.log('found node_modules at '+cwd)
    child_process.exec(`start cmd.exe /k npm ${args}`,{cwd})

    return
  }
  let directoryList = fs.readdirSync(_path);
    directoryList.forEach(function(nextDir){
    if(fs.statSync(_path+'/'+nextDir).isFile()){
      return

    }
    if(/^\./.test(nextDir)){ //.folder beginging with .
      return
    }
    recurse(_path+'/'+nextDir);

  })
}
recurse('./' )
```

Comment: This script could be definitely be useful for running other npm calls in nested directories, but this approach will still require you to do the initial `npm install` within the `c` directory as the `node_modules` directory won't initially exist.