# How to use node_modules for shared projects with downloading extra packages if provided

Tags: javascript, npm, node-modules, npm-install, package.json

I created a shared `package.json` to use for multiple projects. My goal is not to download shared packages in project1, project2 etc. folder's node_modules again and again. It is needed to install shared packages one time and nomore download again in projects' node_modules folders.

And I need to download extra packages which do not exist `/wrapper/node_modules` in each project folders. I defined the expected tree below.

How to I define the whole `package.json` files to do it?

And Is there a way to download all defined packages in projects if there is no any wrapper packages installed?

`Expected File Tree:`

```
+ wrapper
  - package.json
  + node_modules
    + dep1
    + dep2
    + devDep1
  + project1
    - package.json
    + node_modules
      + dep3
      + devDep2
  + project2
    - package.json
    + node_modules
      + dep3
      + dep4
      + devDep3
      + devDep4
```

`Wrapper package.json:`

```
wrapper/package.json


{
  "name": "shared-angular-packages",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "dep1": "1",
    "dep2": "2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "devDep1": "1"
  }
}
```

`Project1 package.json:`

```
wrapper/project1/package.json


{
  "name": "project1-package",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "dep1": "1",
    "dep2": "2",
    "dep3": "3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "devDep1": "1",
    "devDep2": "2"
  }
}
```

`Project2 package.json:`

```
wrapper/project2/package.json


{
  "name": "project2-package",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "dep2": "2",
    "dep3": "3",
    "dep4": "4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "devDep3": "3",
    "devDep4": "4"
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks like an npm hook might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38154379/6672679

Comment: @Ozone thanks for link but there is already installed a node_modules in the wrapper. I just want not to download shared packages in project node_modules again because the shared packages are already installed. I need to download only non-shared packages in each projects.

Comment: What your after is something called workspaces -> https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/workspaces